# Initiate class definition's optional variables with default value same as instance variables

Tags: python, function, class

I have a class definition with optional arguments.
I want to initiate the optional argument with the value of the instance variable.
Is this possible?

**Example:**

```
class Helloworld:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 'abc'
        self.var2 = 123

  def printString(info, message=self.var1):
      print(info + ' - ' + message)
```

In this example, I want to initiate `printString`'s `message` argument as same as instance variable `var1`

Answer (score 2):

No. This is not possible.

By the time `printString` is defined there is no instance (ie, `self` is not defined).

Instead, use `None` as a default value and assign if necessary:

```
class Helloworld:
    def __init__ (self):
        self.var1 = 'abc'
        self.var2 = 123

    def printString (self, info, message=None):
        if message is None:
            message = self.var1
        print(info + ' - ' + message)
```

Also note that you didn't pass `self` to `printString` so `info` will not contain what you may expect it to.

Comment: `message = message or self.var1` will result in `self.var1` when `message` is `0`, `''` or some other value that evaluates as `False` with `bool`. It is somewhat unlikely, true, but worth considering - `message = message if message is not None else self.var1`

Answer (score -1):

Your example code and DeepSpace's answer are about *instance* variable that cannot be directly used as default parameters of methods. But you question title is about class variables and your example method could in fact be static.

So you could use *class* variables that way:

```
class Helloworld:
    var1 = "abc"    # define class variable Foo.var1
    @staticmethod
    def printString(info, message=var1):    # use it as a default parameter
        print(info + ' - ' + message)
```

You can then use:

```
Helloworld.printString("123")
=> 123 - abc
```